# What is this paramater in Pycaret setup?

Tags: pycaret

What are the values `encoding_method` can take for categorical encoding in `setup`, leaving the default leave one out method. I do not see the non default values it can take in the documentation

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument that you are referring to is only valid for PyCaret 3.x and later.

For PyCaret 2.x only One Hot Encoding is [supported](https://github.com/pycaret/pycaret/issues/794).

From the [source code](https://github.com/pycaret/pycaret/blob/3.0.0.rc3/pycaret/internal/preprocess/preprocessor.py#L8) it seems that LeaveOneOutEncoder ([default](https://github.com/pycaret/pycaret/blob/3.0.0.rc3/pycaret/regression/functional.py#L247)), OneHotEncoder and OrdinalEncoder are supported.

From what I can understand you can use them in the following manner:

```
from category_encoders.leave_one_out import LeaveOneOutEncoder

encoding_method = LeaveOneOutEncoder(
                        handle_missing="return_nan",
                        handle_unknown="value",
                        random_state=self.seed,
                    )
```

Package documentation can also be found [here](https://contrib.scikit-learn.org/category_encoders/index.html) for reference.